# Saving Data between Free and Paid Versions

Tags: ios, icloud

I am going to release both a paid and a free version of my app that essentially saves pictures and some meta-data. If a user starts at the free version and upgrades to the paid version, I want the data they created in the free version to be there when they get the paid one. The only idea I have to do this would be to backup data to iCloud and give both apps the same iCloud backup address, but is there an easier way to do it than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do what you are asking about in a few of my apps. The basic way you can share the data is to use a private, named pasteboard. Two apps can share a private, named pasteboard as long as both apps are from the same developer.

The basic idea requires both the lite and paid version have their own custom URL schemes. The user runs the paid version. The paid version looks for the URL scheme of the lite version. If there, it shows a "data transfer" button. When the user taps the button, your apps roughly do the following:

1. App A (full verion) looks for custom URL scheme of App B (lite version).
2. If found show "transfer" button somewhere appropriate.
3. User taps button in App A
4. App A launches App B with URL that says "send me your data".
5. App A exits and App B is launched.
6. App B handles URL request.
7. App B packages up its data and puts in a named UIPasteboard (name hardcoded in to App A and App B).
8. App B launches App A with URL that says "you have data".
9. App B exist and App A is relaunched.
10. App A handle URL request.
11. App A gets data from pasteboard, removes it from pasteboard, installs data into self, and refreshes.
12. App A informs user transfer is complete and recommends user to remove App B.
13. User rejoices at how easy that was.

This process isn't trivial to code but it makes for a trivial user experience. I came up with this long before iCloud existed.

This process could be modified to use iCloud instead of a `UIPasteboard`. But that has the downside of requiring the user to be logged into iCloud and connected to the Internet. Using a pasteboard is all local.

Comment: I like the approach, but are you at all concerned that some other app might discover your lite URL scheme and use step 4 to request your app's data?

Comment: Never crossed my mind until now. :) But under iOS 7 it isn't possible. Apple, as of iOS 7, only allows two apps to access the same private pasteboard if the two apps are from the same developer (actually have the same base bundle id). And also, both apps are hardcoded to launch their own counterpart. So even if a rogue app launched the lite app, the lite app would only launch the paid app, not the rogue app.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! Do you happen to have a link to a tutorial or example code that may go more in depth with this?

Comment: No tutorial. Just work on it one step at a time.

Comment: If you are curious about using maddy's pseudocode to do this, you may want to check out these links I found that go into the UIPasteboard API in detail and give some coding examples!  [UIPasteboard Example](http://hayageek.com/uipasteboard-example-read-write-share/)  [UIPasteboard Tutorial](http://enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/)

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is via a remote server to which you have saved the users information (probably via a username and password login). This could be done by saving the user meta data to XML / plist and then uploading this. You would then retrieve the users information on the paid version once installed via e.g a retrieve existing account option.

Comment: This is far from the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Since both apps live in their own sandbox, sharing local data between them will probably not be possible. I'm not even sure that the same iCloud backup will work.

You could instead offer only one app but implement an in-app purchase to activate the full version?

Comment: Two apps from the same developer can share data using a named `UIPasteboard`.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that this exists. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Please not the point that upgrading an app from one version to another version won't clear the data from user preference. The data that are stored in the user defaults or local storage (SQLite or core data) won't be lost while upgrading the app.  Please check whether it is helpful in your case.

Comment: This seems to be missing the point. What is being asked is about a case where the free and paid versions are different apps, whereas you are talking about upgrading the same app from one version to a later version.

Comment: I think switching from free to paid version is same as normal version upgrade and no data in the app's local storage will be lost.

Comment: It is not the same if the free and paid versions are submitted as different apps to the app store. Then, "upgrade" from free to paid is technically not the right word, but still, it is different from just an upgrade of the same app.